# Which one is correct when we use myself?

Tags: grammar

1.) I have to prove myself that I'm a good leader.
2.) I have to prove to myself that I'm a good leader.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Both are correct. But each one has its own indication.

> I have to prove **myself** that I'm a good leader.

Using "myself" here is for emphasizing the fact that you are a good leader and feel the need to prove that to others.

- "Myself" can be omitted safely without changing the meaning of the sentence.

> I have to prove **to myself** that I'm a good leader.

The addition of "to" shifts the need to prove that fact to *yourself* instead of to *other people*.

- Omitting "to myself" changes the sentence to be directed toward *others*.

Comment: If my answer is not sufficient or provides wrong information, then pointing that out would be more helpful than leaving a downvote for mysterious reasons.